# Passar um objeto para Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um `Foreach` em uma tabela, eu preciso assim que o usuario clicar em uma linha, abrir uma modal com os dados do objeto contido naquela linha.

O Foreach:

```
     @foreach (PedidoModel pedido in @Model.Entidades)
                {
                    <tr title="Clique para exibir detalhes" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td>@pedido.Pessoa.Nome</td>
                        <td>@pedido.DataEntrega</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>R$ @pedido.ValorTotal</td>
                        <td>@pedido.Endereco</td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="label label-success">@pedido.Status</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Quando o usario cliclar no `tr` eu pretendo abrir uma `modal` que esta em uma `partialView`

Eu tentei colocar a  `partialView` dentro do `foreach` e passar a model na chamada, assim :

```
 @Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Unidade/Views/Pedidos/_DetalhePedido.cshtml",pedido)
```

Porém a `Modal` aparece na própria pagina, sem ser na `modal`.

Antes de ter que passar as informações para modal eu abria ela assim:

```
 $("#myModal").on("show", function () {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
}).on("hidden", function () {
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
});
```

Se alguém souber uma forma de fazer isso ficarei grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na pagina em que pretende chamar a modal, deixe somente a tag inicial da modal

```
<div class="modal" id="abrir"></div>
```

Ja na PartialView _DetalhePedido coloque todo o resto do código da modal

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

No html das das tr coloque um atributo para carregar os dados

```
<tr class="trClick" data-pedido="@pedido">
</tr>
```

Na chamada da pagina, vc pode fazer por script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".trClick").click(function(){
        var DadosPedido = $(this).attr("data-pedido");
        $("#abrir").load("/Pedidos/_DetalhePedido/" + DadosPedido);
        $("#abrir").modal();
   })
})
```

No controller da modal, vc pode tratar os dados ou simplesmente carrega-los

```
public ActionResult __DetalhePedido(Pedido dados)
{
  return PartialView(Dados);
}
```